i2c-tools are installed, but i2cdetect returns "command not found" error
I've got a raspberry pi zero (with a fresh install of the current raspian OS) and I'm trying to find the i2c address of a connected display.  When I try to scan for devices using i2cdetect -y 1 I get the following error:
bash: i2cdetect: command not found
I've tried the following:

Confirmed that i2c tools and python3-smbus are installed with:

sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
sudo apt-get install python3-smbus


Enabled i2c in sudo raspi-config
Rebooting: Does not help.


"with a fresh install of the current raspian OS" What OS is installed (detail including version)? There never has been a "raspian" - current is Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm (but I wouldn't even try this on a Pi Zero). What is CONNECTED?

Interesting... the i2ctools have always behaved a little strangely. For example, if you don't have i2c1 enabled, you get an error like this (on my RPi OS Lite 'bullseye'):
$ i2cdetect -y 1
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or `/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory

OTOH, if I do have i2c1 enabled, I can run i2cdetect -y 1 without error. I know the error I listed above was not what you saw, but you may want to check that it's i2c1 you have enabled - just to make sure.
Beyond that, here's a couple of things you can try:

This will tell you where (if anywhere) i2cdetect is installed:

$ whereis i2cdetect
i2cdetect: /usr/sbin/i2cdetect /usr/share/man/man8/i2cdetect.8.gz


This will check your PATH - make sure whatever folder whereis found your i2cdetect in - is on your PATH:

$ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games 

Check those & get back to us w/ your findings.

thanks for the quick response.  /usr/sbin was not in PATH; it's working now that I've added it.

Adding /user/sbin to the PATH is a better solution, but another option is this python code: python i2cdetect

Note that /usr/sbin is a default part of $PATH on pretty much every normal linux distro including Rpi OS -- something weird happened to you.  Many common everyday commands are there (you will probably recognize a few things in ls /usr/sbin/). Possibly also worth noting that /sbin is  on most contemporary distros (again including Rpi OS) a symlink to /usr/sbin so if one of those is enabled they both will work.
